# Some ligatures of the 'Devanagari Script' are not displayed correctly

Tags: fonts, input-method

I want to enter the following line in Devanagari script.

[image]

In Emacs, I set the input mode to "Devanagari Inscript" and typed it in.
And this is what is displayed:

[image]

The font in the above example is *Noto Sans Devanagari*.

Many Devanagari characters are ligatures, i.e., they are themselves made from two or more characters. Though some ligatures are displayed correctly many are not, as can be seen by comparing the attached images.

How do I fix this?